# Bash Character transformations

Tags: linux, bash, character-encoding

Here's the latest from my terminal.

```
                                                          E┬$?: N⎺ ⎽┤c▒ °☃┌e ⎺⎼ d☃⎼ec├⎺⎼≤
┴▒±⎼▒┼├@└e⎽⎺⎽:·/de┴e┌⎺⎻└e┼├/⎽⎻┌☃├├e⎼$ └▒┼ └▒⎼▒├▒⎺┼
N⎺ └▒┼┤▒┌ e┼├⎼≤ °⎺⎼ └▒⎼▒├▒⎺┼
See '└▒┼ 7 ┤┼d⎺c┤└e┼├ed' °⎺⎼ ▒e┌⎻ ┬▒e┼ └▒┼┤▒┌ ⎻▒±e⎽ ▒⎼e ┼⎺├ ▒┴▒☃┌▒b┌e↓
┴▒±⎼▒┼├@└e⎽⎺⎽:·/de┴e┌⎺⎻└e┼├/⎽⎻┌☃├├e⎼$ ⎻☃┼± ±⎺±⎺┌e↓c⎺└
PING ±⎺±⎺┌e↓c⎺└ (216↓58↓217↓36) 56(84) b≤├e⎽ ⎺° d▒├▒↓
64 b≤├e⎽ °⎼⎺└ de┼▮3⎽1▮↑☃┼↑°36↓1e1▮▮↓┼e├ (216↓58↓217↓36): ☃c└⎻_⎽e─=1 ├├┌=63 ├☃└e=29↓▮ └⎽
64 b≤├e⎽ °⎼⎺└ de┼▮3⎽1▮↑☃┼↑°36↓1e1▮▮↓┼e├ (216↓58↓217↓36): ☃c└⎻_⎽e─=2 ├├┌=63 ├☃└e=32↓4 └⎽
64 b≤├e⎽ °⎼⎺└ de┼▮3⎽1▮↑☃┼↑°36↓1e1▮▮↓┼e├ (216↓58↓217↓36): ☃c└⎻_⎽e─=3 ├├┌=63 ├☃└e=27↓4 └⎽
64 b≤├e⎽ °⎼⎺└ de┼▮3⎽1▮↑☃┼↑°36↓1e1▮▮↓┼e├ (216↓58↓217↓36): ☃c└⎻_⎽e─=4 ├├┌=63 ├☃└e=25↓9 └⎽
^C
↑↑↑ ±⎺±⎺┌e↓c⎺└ ⎻☃┼± ⎽├▒├☃⎽├☃c⎽ ↑↑↑
4 ⎻▒c┐e├⎽ ├⎼▒┼⎽└☃├├ed← 4 ⎼ece☃┴ed← ▮% ⎻▒c┐e├ ┌⎺⎽⎽← ├☃└e 32▮3└⎽
⎼├├ └☃┼/▒┴±/└▒│/└de┴ = 25↓927/28↓721/32↓426/2↓415 └⎽
┴▒±⎼▒┼├@└e⎽⎺⎽:·/de┴e┌⎺⎻└e┼├/⎽⎻┌☃├├e⎼$ E┴e⎼≤├▒☃┼± ☃⎽ ☃┼ ▒ ┼e┬ ┌▒┼±┤▒±e
E┴e⎼≤├▒☃┼±: c⎺└└▒┼d ┼⎺├ °⎺┤┼d
┴▒±⎼▒┼├@└e⎽⎺⎽:·/de┴e┌⎺⎻└e┼├/⎽⎻┌☃├├e⎼$ ┌⎽
▒⎻⎻↓┘⎽  c⎺┼°☃±  D⎺c┐e⎼°☃┌e  d⎺c┐e⎼☃≥e↓⎽▒  ┼⎺de_└⎺d┤┌e⎽  ⎻▒c┐▒±e↓┘⎽⎺┼  Re▒d└e↓└d  README↓└d
┴▒±⎼▒┼├@└e⎽⎺⎽:·/de┴e┌⎺⎻└e┼├/⎽⎻┌☃├├e⎼$
```

Now, I'm aware that `cat`ing binary files causes all kinds of crazy stuff to happen to your terminal. But I've never asked about it before. I'm trying to track down what exactly would cause this character transformation.

Everything seems to work normally. I can't read the output, but ping commands produce output that behaves as I would expect. `ls` has the same color coding. custom scripts have the same output (just transformed).

**What character sequence would cause this consistent transformation?**

typing `reset` puts me back into sanity.

Am I getting a [character transformation via console codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)? If so, can I prank friends with this? (`alias ls=ls #+some character transformation`). Note: I don't want this to have a possibility of `ls` turning into `rm -rf` or anything else malicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `smacs` (`enter_alt_charset_mode`) [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) sequence being entered into the terminal. It can be switched back with the `rmacs` (`exit_alt_charset_mode`) terminfo sequence.

```
echo "$(tput rmacs)"
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Now I have yet another way to make people stop looking over my shoulder
`alias human_mode=echo "$(tput rmacs)"`
`alias alien_mode=echo "$(tput smacs)"`
`alias go_away='alien_mode; tail -f /var/log/syslog'`